# Order results with mySQL

Tags: mysql

If I have a table with data in the following format:

```
id  itemID  projectID   position_X   position_Y
________________________________________________
1    2677      10         -289         -27
2    2653      10         -403          253
3    337       10         -23          -77
4    2456      10          50           130
```

and I need to create 3 different queries to output results as a list where:

1. "X" axel is more important
2. "Y" axel is more important
3. Whatever makes more sense based on the chart

How would I do that?

[image]

Comment: what is the query you have right now?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but at a glance, it sounds like you want to `SELECT` your data and then use the `ORDER BY position_X ASC, position_Y ASC` clause to sort it by X position, then Y position? Is that close?

Comment: @DaveL It has to be a list, ordered top down, where the highest X and Y values will be on the top and lowest X and Y at the bottom. I just was not sure how to resolve it when one point will have X=1 Y=2 and another X=2 Y=1... This is where I wanted to use query option 1 and 2 to indicate priority, otherwise query 3.

Comment: @santa I think I understand you now, so given this conflict you've described here, is okay to have a point listed more than once? For example, you might have (1, 2) in the list where X is priority, and again at a different position in the list where Y is priority (since the higher Y value would push it up that list). Or do we want to list each point only once?

Comment: @DaveL Only once per query. I may have a drop-down selector to indicate which one is taking precedence. By default I guess Importance should be a default priority, but again, only for those border-line cases, which I hope won't be too many. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, given the comments on the OP, I would say your 3 queries would be something like:

1. `SELECT position_X, position_Y FROM <tablename> ORDER BY position_X DESC, position_Y DESC;`
2. `SELECT position_X, position_Y FROM <tablename> ORDER BY position_Y DESC, position_X DESC;`
3. `SELECT positon_X, position_Y FROM <tablename> ORDER BY <desiredcolumn> DESC;`

(Keeping in mind I don't know the table name, or the exact sort order of the third query)

Given the data you've posted, outputting these three queries in order would give you:

First Query:

50, 130

-23, -77

-289, -27

-403, 253

Second Query:

-403, 253

50, 130

-289, -27

-23, -77

(Query three isn't certain due to not having a decision on what sort order)

Comment: Thanks @DaveL. This looks quite reasonable!

Comment: Just thought of something, which should've been in the OP. What is I have multiple entries, say multiple users entered the data and I need to aggregate the results, how would I group such results?

Comment: @santa - you mean sort the lists by the user that entered them? To do that, you would need to add a column to store user identifiers to the table. Then, on data entry, store the user's ID in that column for each record. Then, when `SELECT`ing your data, add another `ORDER BY` clause to sort by the user ID column. (ie `ORDER BY user_ID ASC, position_X DESC, position_Y DESC`)

Comment: No, I mean, assuming there's a user column and there are multiple users that arranged their items on a diagram, I will need to aggregate all data for items in the same list format. But in this case, I think, I'll need to average the coordinates for each item before displaying the list.

Comment: Ahh, well, MySQL does have an `AVG()` function, but to use it, you would need to use the `GROUP BY` clause on the user ID.

ex. `SELECT AVG(position_X) AS AVGX, AVG(position_Y) AS AVGY FROM <tablename> GROUP BY user_ID ORDER BY AVGX DESC, AVGY DESC;`

(this may not be exactly it, as it's late, and I'm a little braindead, but should be close enough to fill in the blanks with a little google-fu)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I tried and it does work, however I need the list of the itemIDs based on avg coordinates and right now I get a list of coordinate pairs. I should've noticed this yesterday... Sorry, my bad.